# Transforming a one-hot encoded variable to one column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have age columns like so that are dummy encoded.
How can I transform these columns to one column using dplyr?

Input:

```
  age_0-10 age_11-20 age_21-30 age_31-40 age_41-50 age_51-60 gender
1 0        1         0         0         0         0         0
2 0        0         1         0         0         0         1
3 0        0         0         1         0         0         0
4 0        1         0         0         0         0         1
5 0        0         0         0         0         1         1
```

Expected output:

```
age         gender
1 11-20     0
2 21-30     1
3 31-40     0
4 11-20     1
5 51-60     1
```

Comment: Check out the `pivot_longer` function and top example - https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html

Answer (score 7):

A possible solution, now, thanks to @Adam's comment, with `names_prefix`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  check.names = FALSE,
  `age_0-10` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
  `age_11-20` = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L),
  `age_21-30` = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
  `age_31-40` = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L),
  `age_41-50` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L),
  `age_51-60` = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L),
  gender = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L)
)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(col=starts_with("age"), names_to="age", names_prefix="age_") %>% 
  filter(value==1) %>%
  select(age, gender, -value)

#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>   age   gender
#>   <chr>  <int>
#> 1 11-20      0
#> 2 21-30      1
#> 3 31-40      0
#> 4 11-20      1
#> 5 51-60      1
```

Comment: If you use `names_prefix = "age_"` in the `pivot_longer()` statement you can remove the final `mutate()` line.

Comment: Thanks, @Adam, to let me know that! `names_prefix` had escaped to my mind. I have edited my answer accordingly. Good point, Adam!

Comment: No problem! There are so many little options in those functions it's hard to keep track of. I just happen to be doing a lot of pivoting recently, so it is all fresh in my mind.

Comment: This is great! If the age columns had a suffix, lets say `age_0-10_col`, `age_11-20_col`, etc.. how could i get rid of the suffix?

Comment: @Eisen: to remove the suffix `_col`, just add the following line to the end of my code: `%>% mutate(age = str_remove(age, "_col$"))`. I have tested that and works! Hope this helps you!

Comment: Perhaps it is basic R, but perhaps add something about why the backticks are necessary? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.) Attribution to this comment is ***not*** necessary (most readers will have zero interest in it).

Comment: Thanks, @Peter Mortensen, for your comment. Honestly, I do not think such an explanation is really needed. However, if you think it really needed, please you are welcome to insert yourself that explanation.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a way in `dplyr` using `c_across()`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(age = str_remove(names(.)[which(c_across(starts_with("age")) == 1)], "^age_")) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(age, gender)

# # A tibble: 5 x 2
#   age   gender
#   <chr>  <int>
# 1 11-20      0
# 2 21-30      1
# 3 31-40      0
# 4 11-20      1
# 5 51-60      1
```

Answer (score 4):

Try the base R code below using `max.col`

```
cbind(
  age = gsub("^age_", "", head(names(df), -1)[max.col(df[-ncol(df)])]),
  df[ncol(df)]
)
```

which gives

```
    age gender
1 11-20      0
2 21-30      1
3 31-40      0
4 11-20      1
5 51-60      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  mutate(age = pmap_chr(select(cur_data(), !gender), 
                        ~ names(df)[-ncol(df)][as.logical(c(...))])) %>%
  select(age, gender)

        age gender
1 age_11-20      0
2 age_21-30      1
3 age_31-40      0
4 age_11-20      1
5 age_51-60      1
```